# Trying to add multiple checkbox into an array on Android Studio

Tags: android, checkbox

Im doing an App on Android Studio and im trying to add all my checkbox IDs into an array, so i can use it , without doing it manually.
I tried to do it on another way, but i didn´t find nothing on google that help me,

So here is my goal:

I want to get all my Checkbox ids, so i can get their text. And i don´t want to do it manually because i got alot of checkboxs.

I tried to write a code by myself but i´m getting an message error.
Here is my code:

```
 CheckBox[] MinhaCheckBox;
    SharedPreferences Dados;
   String MinhaPasta = "Pasta";
    String valor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btn_Gerar(View v)
    {
        Dados = getSharedPreferences(MinhaPasta,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor Edita = Dados.edit();
        int IDTexBoz[] = {R.id.checkBox,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5,
                R.id.checkBox6,R.id.checkBox7,R.id.checkBox8};
        for(int i = 0 ; i < IDTexBoz.length; i++)
        {


 *//I GOT AN ERRO HERE. please help me.*
 * // when i try to put mycheckbox on my array, i got th error!*
            MinhaCheckBox[i] = (CheckBox)findViewById(IDTexBoz[i]);

        }
        for (int a= 0; a < MinhaCheckBox.length;a++)
        {
            if(MinhaCheckBox[a].isChecked())
            valor += MinhaCheckBox[a].getText().toString() + ";";
        }
        Edita.putString("Dado", valor);
        Edita.commit();

        Intent MeuIntent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(MeuIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized MinhaCheckBox. Have you?

Comment: It will be easier to find solution, if you provide the exact error message.

Comment: I did, check out the first line please.

Comment: It's just declaration. What about initialization?

Comment: ohhh thank you, i didn´t notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your checkbox array.

Comment: It would be something like...
CheckBox[] MinhaCheckBox = new CheckBox[IDTexBoz.length];
Put the line before the for statement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example could help, you don't need to store the ID name, do something like this..

```
for(int i=1;i<=12 ;i++){ 
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("checkBox"+i, "id",getPackageName()); 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(resID);
        //Handle cb object here  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Very Simple.

```
int IDTexBoz[] = {R.id.checkBox,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4,R.id.checkBox5,
                R.id.checkBox6,R.id.checkBox7,R.id.checkBox8};
//Here is code for array initialization. 
MinhaCheckBox = new CheckBox[IDTexBoz.length];
```